# Is there any explicit relationship between $Cov(X^2,Y^2)$ and $Cov(X,Y)$ for any random variables X,Y?

Tags: probability

The questions in the title, but I haven't been able to find any sort of relationship. Specifically, I've been trying to work through the derivation in the link, as the comments imply that the solution works for all $X,Y$.

http://falkenblog.blogspot.ca/2008/07/formula-for-varxy.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no answer for general distributions but the link assumes that $(X,Y)$ is normal, which makes all the difference. (Actually, the link is faulty by only assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are separately normal, which is notoriously not sufficient to deduce that $(X,Y)$ is normal.)

So, let us assume that $(X,Y)$ is **centered normal**, and, without loss of generality, that the variances of $X$ and $Y$ are both $1$. Let $\varrho=\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)$. Then $\mathrm{Cov}(X^2,Y^2)=E[X^2Y^2]-1$. Furthermore, one can rewrite $Y$ as $Y=\varrho X+\sigma Z$ where $\sigma^2+\varrho^2=1$ and where $(X,Z)$ is i.i.d. standard normal. This yields
$$
X^2Y^2=\varrho^2X^4+2\varrho\sigma X^3Z+\sigma^2X^2Z^2,
$$
hence, using $E[X^4]=3$, $E[X^3]=E[Z]=0$ and $E[X^2]=E[Z^2]=1$, one gets
$$
E[X^2Y^2]=\varrho^2E[X^4]+2\varrho\sigma E[X^3]E[Z]+\sigma^2E[X^2]E[Z^2]=3\varrho^2+0+\sigma^2=1+2\varrho^2.
$$
Finally, for every **centered normal** $(X,Y)$,
$$
\mathrm{Cov}(X^2,Y^2)=2\cdot\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)^2.
$$
The noncentered case can be dealt with by the same method.